# Powershell: rewrite 1-D array entries from multiple substring cuts

Tags: arrays, powershell

My array consists of multiple members like the file structure below. I would like to cut each member into multiple substrings and reassemble. I know this works with a single substring cut but when I try to assemble multiple substrings together, it does not work. How might I fix this?

```
#File Structure: [0-9]{3} [A-Z] [A-Z]{2} [0-9]{2}K[0-9]b [0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2} [A-Z] [0-9]{2} [A-Z]{3}.*
#Example: 110 B CC 12K48b 02 SC C 01 BRP

$fileList=@()
$labelStr=@()

$fileList+=(get-childitem -filter *.tif -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match '^[0-9]{3} (B|F) [A-Z]{2} ..K..b [0-9]{2}.*'}).Name
$labelStr+=(($fileList.Substring(27,3)+" "+$fileList.Substring(16,2)+" "+$fileList.Substring(0,3)) | Sort-Object | Get-Unique)

$labelStr #I would expect an array member to look like: BRP 02 110. However, I get:
```

---

```
PS:>
BRP
02
110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single pipeline and let PowerShell collect the results in an array for you:

```bash
[array] $labelStr =
  (Get-ChildItem -Filter *.tif -Recurse).Name |
  Where-Object { $_ -match '^[0-9]{3} (B|F) [A-Z]{2} ..K..b [0-9]{2}\.+$' } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.Substring(27, 3) + " " + $_.Substring(16, 2) + " " + $_.Substring(0, 3)
  } |
  Sort-Object -Unique
```

---

As for what you tried:

`$fileList` contains an *array* of file names, and when you call `.Substring()` on that array, it is called on *each element* of that array, with the results also becoming an *array* of results, courtesy of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) (which you're also using to obtain the file names via `.Name`).

Instead, you must process the names *one by one*, as shown above.

---

A simplified example that attempts to use `.Substring()` calls to reverse the characters in the input string:

```bash
$names = 'f1', 'f2'
```

```bash
# WRONG: operating directly on the array doesn't work as expected.
PS> $names.Substring(1, 1) + $names.Substring(0, 1)

1
2
f
f
```

```bash
# OK: operate on each array element.
PS> $names | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(1, 1) + $_.SubString(0, 1) }

1f
2f
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Brian; my pleasure (I've also added a simplified example to the answer). Also note that you could operate on `.BaseName` instead of `.Name`, in which case you wouldn't have to worry about the filename extension in the regex.